# VPN is up but cannot ping/ssh..etc

Tags: vpn

I have a VPN, configured using a host to host setup. They are :

AIX  using IKE (ipsec)

Redhat  using libreswan (ipsec)

The tunnel is up, I can see that by querying from both ends. So far so good.
Unfortunately I cannot ping from either side, the pings do not returned anything.
However when using tcpdump  at either end, I do see ESP packets coming thru.

My ipsec.conf used and imported into aix ok is:

```
conn %default
 keyingtries=1
 type=tunnel
 auth=esp
 authby=secret
 pfs=no
 rekeymargin=900s
 rekeyfuzz=90%
 auto=add

conn aix
 left=170.22.7.44
 right=170.22.11.159
```

So is this  a routing or ipsec rule issue ?

When the tunnel is made active, on the aix side default ipsec rules are applied, these look OK.
On the Redhat side, no rules are generated in iptables, just have the default rules, so I have stopped itables. 
Should I be doing this, do I need rules in the iptables to work, if so, what are by chance.

My routing is like this (ips masked):
redhat: 170.22.7.44       aix: 170.22.11.159

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
170.22.7.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         170.22.7.1      0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
```

aix

```
default            170.22.11.1       UG        2  25324037 en0      -      -   
127/8              127.0.0.1         U         0       562 lo0      -      -   
170.22.11.0        170.22.11.159     UHSb      0         0 en0      -      -   =>
170.22.11/24       170.22.11.159     U         3    642941 en0      -      -   
170.22.11.159      127.0.0.1         UGHS      0       102 lo0      -      -   
170.22.11.255      170.22.11.159     UHSb      0         1 en0      -
```

Answer (score 1):

So after much searching, I was missing this rule on the linux side, once inserted VPN all looking goos.

```
ACCEPT     esp  --  170.22.7.44          170.22.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have IPSEC issue: you didn't define left/right subnets in your configuration, so IPSEC doesn't know which packets it must encrypt and send to a tunnel.

In StrongSWAN, the keywords are rightsubnet/leftsubnet.

Comment: Yup already tried that, on  a previous config, no luck there either